# Java: File content not in text area

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

When I open a file with this Java program, the file content appears in the console, but on in the text area.

Can someone tell me how I can get the file content in the text area?

Output: [Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuA9x.png)

Code:

```
 private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String filename = jTextField1.getText();
        Graphics g = jPanel1.getGraphics();
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);
```

Comment: First of all you need to have a textarea. In your code you're just writing to standard out.

Answer (score 1):

Read the `JTextArea` API.

You can use:

```
textArea.read(...);
```

to read a file directly into a `JTextArea` (or any text component).